# Go through a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe, which looks like the following:

```
time   colA  colB  colC  colD
9:30   20     1    1      A34
9:30   45    -1    5      B54
9:30   20     1    3      A34 
9:31   20     1    1      C65
9:32   40    -1    4      D42
9:33   20     1    3      F32
9:34   20     1    1      H63
9:35   20     1    4      M24
9:40   100   -1    1      J73
9:43   70    -1    1      P98
9:44   70    -1    3      I87
```

I want to evaluate how many rows with the same value in col A and in col B are in a time window of 5 minutes, starting with the time stamp from colC = 3. So here row 3 would be the starting point, row4, row 6, row 7, row 8 should be added and then also row 1, since it has the same colD value so the whole run has a value of 6.  Any idea on how to implement that?

Comment: time window of +5 and -5? and this applies for every timestamp where `colC = 3` ?

Comment: only +5 and yes for every colC = 3

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, for every timestamp where colC = 3, but the next ("nearest") entry in the run has to have colC=1 ( besides having the same colA and colB).

Comment: What would be final expected output for the data shared? Only rows 1, 4, 6, 7 and 8? Rest of the columns should be ignored?

Comment: I have a big dataframe, which contains a lot of this "runs" and the output should be that i have x "runs" with 6 elements (like in the example= number of rows), y "runs" with e.g.10 elements, etc.